# Email link opens email client with a Questionnaire in the Body

Tags: mailto

I have a question I can't seem to find an answer to. It may also be that I cannot figure out how to concisely word it to look for it most effectively.

Here is what I want to happen.

When someone clicks my "Email me" link (mailto: (I am using a .js to hide the real email address from the screen to filter spam) it opens up their email client, as usual, but the email already has a subject line AND the Body of the email already has text in it (A Questionnaire for them to fill out.)

Any help in the right direction will be much appreciated!

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

the mailto supports subject and body as params

```
mailto:you@yourdomain.com?subject=Your Subject&body=Message for the body
```